# Rails Search a field from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this statement in my model:

class Curso

```
     def self.search(username)
        where("LOWER(curso.user.name) LIKE ?", "%#{username}%")
     end
```

I want to bring the name of a user from the user table. A 'curso' belongs to a user.

Do you know what the query can be?

thanks!

Comment: Joins(:user).where("lower(users.name) like......

Comment: its not working

Comment: what is not working here, you need to include more detail such as expected results and desired results

Comment: i have 2 tables. one is curso(with a user_id field) and the other one is user(with 2 fields, id and name). a curso belongs to a user. i pass the parameter username and i want to get all the users that have that name. im calling this function from the cursos model.

Comment: can you add the actual create statements for the pair of tables? This will be a much simpler exercise if we can see the sql structure.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 def self.search(username)
    includes(:user).where(users: { name: username.downcase })
 end
```